# Создание двух объектов одним определением класс

Tags: java

можно ли создать два или больше объектов в такой или подобный способ, т.е. чтоб не повторять название класса экземпляр которого создаем дважды:

```
FirstClass
    obj1 = new FirstClass();
    obj2 = new FirstClass();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Object obj1 = new Object(), obj2 = new Object();
```

Comment: супер, то что надо